# NiFi 'Schema Registry' is invalid

Tags: apache-nifi

Add JsonTreeReader but invalid. 'Schema Registry' is invalid because The 'Use 'Schema Name' Property Schema Access Strategy requires that the Schema Registry property be set

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse Use 'Schema Name' Property is set  in Schema Access Strategy of your Controller Service.You can choose Infer Schema.

Comment: No, this is because of version. It's working fine in 1.9 but broke in 1.8.

Comment: Sorry.I find the tips in your pic,that the Schema Registry property need to be set.You can try try again.@Chandler.Huang

Comment: No problem Kong. Appreciate your comment. Thanks.